# Rails 4 active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models, Project and TodoItem. Please see below table structures and Models below.

What I am trying to do query all **todo_items** where a**ssigned = current_user.fullname** and **completed_at is nil** grouped_by **project name** and Ordered_by the **project name**.

Then I want to loop out something similar to this:

PROJECT 1 Name

- ToDo_Item 1 content
- ToDo_Item 2 content
- ToDo_Item 3 content

PROJECT 2 Name

- ToDo_Item 1 content
- ToDo_Item 2 content
- ToDo_Item 3 content

Table Structure:

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "details"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

---

```
create_table "todo_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "assigned"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "completed_at"
  end
```

Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project 
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far for your query?

Comment: @projects = Project.includes(:todo_items).where(:todo_items => {'assigned = ?' ,current_user.fullname })

Comment: This works. @projects = Project.includes(:todo_items) I am just having a problem only getting projects with open todo items for the current _user

Comment: Is it important that it is the users fullname you find the todo items by? Or could you make a simple, in your user model, `has_many: todo_items`

Answer (score 1):

For your complete solution

you can try this

```
@projects = Project.includes(:todo_items).where(todo_items: {assigned: current_user.fullname, completed_at: nil }).group("projects.name").order("projects.name")
```

Comment: This was what I needed. I actually didn't need the .group("projects.name") if I wanted to list all todo_items for each Project. But this works great. Unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation to mark this answer +1. But Thank you again

Comment: Welcome @DamonDelcoro you can do it anytime after you get higher reputation.!! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

You just need to add `.where`:

`@projects = Project.includes(:todo_items).where(completed_at: nil)`